# Issue with data insert not finding an Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my project, I have in place a quoting system. This worked before, I have made changes to some of the things that are involved. The changes were made a while ago and I just had to do a quote and it is failing on the insert of Parts in the QuoteDetail table.

The error is that it cannot find `Eparts_ProductMasterId.` Eparts is a SQL view and I am not inserting it into this, it is read-only. I am pulling the info from the cart, but need it to find other info from this table. Which according to my locals, I have everything I need, all it has to do is insert it into the `QuoteDetails` table.

Also I am not inserting the `ProductMasterId` into the `QuoteDetails` table. It fails on the `db.SaveChanges();`

Before I go posting a bunch of code I will post the part that is failing and if you need to see more I will post what you need. I am not even calling a `ProductMasterId` and `ProductMasterId` is part of the SQL View.

Here is the part that fails to save. It passes the `if` and goes to the `else` and is not a complete part.

```
foreach (var item in CartItems)
{
    var part = db.ExtParts.Where(a => a.Material == item.Material).FirstOrDefault();
    var type = db.Parts.Where(a => a.Material == item.Material).FirstOrDefault();

    if ((type.Class == "MACH") || (type.Class == "PRL"))
    {
        QuoteDetail qd = new QuoteDetail
                    {
                        Material = item.Material,
                        QuoteId = quote.QuoteId,
                        Quantity = item.Count,
                        UnitPrice = part.MachinedPrice,
                        IsDelete = false,
                        CreatedBy = UserData.FirstName,
                        CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now
                    };
        db.QuoteDetail.Add(qd);
    }
    else
    {
        if (part.Complete != true)
        {
            QuoteDetail qd = new QuoteDetail
                        {
                            Material = item.Material,
                            QuoteId = quote.QuoteId,
                            Quantity = item.Count,
                            UnitPrice = part.SellingPrice,
                            IsDelete = false,
                            CreatedBy = UserData.FirstName,
                            CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now
                        };
            db.QuoteDetail.Add(qd);
        }
        else
        {
            QuoteDetail qd = new QuoteDetail
                        {
                            Material = item.Material,
                            QuoteId = quote.QuoteId,
                            Quantity = item.Count,
                            UnitPrice = part.LastCost,
                            IsDelete = false,
                            CreatedBy = UserData.FirstName,
                            CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now
                        };
            db.QuoteDetail.Add(qd);
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have had this issue before putting a

```
public ExtParts EParts { get; set; }
```

in another model but this fixes that issue

```
public virtual ExtParts EParts { get; set; }
```

This is in the `OrderDetails` model or am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I looked through my code again and found that I added the `public virtual ExtParts EParts { get; set; }` to the model and it was not needed. I already had it in the ViewModel so it was not needed in the actual model. The Model is used to save the records and when it was looking at the SQL View it was faulting out. Does not fault out on the others that are in the Model, but they are not SQL Views either, they are other related Models.

Comment: What is the KEY you have specified in EParts

Comment: [Key]
 public Guid ProductMasterId { get; set; }

Comment: Is your ProductMasterId supposed to be autogenerated? or is that really representing any product table Id?

Comment: It represents a ProductMasterId. No it is not auto generated. It is in the SQL View so it is definitely in the ProductMaster table. The View is just a comprise of 2 tables, parts and ProductMaster. With a join on Material, which is a string "Guid". and the Key of the Parts table.

Comment: Are you able to run this if you add AsNoTracking to the ExtParts? Just verify without attaching it to the context.

Comment: If this is what you are referring to, It is already in there as it is on all my SQL Views.   [NotMapped]
public virtual DbSet<ExtParts> ExtParts { get; set; }

Comment: No, it is like  db.ExtParts.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.Material == item.Material).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @RajeeshMadambat Just got back on this. I tried this but it did not make a difference. I still get the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed

```
public virtual ExtParts EParts { get; set; }
```

from the Model. It was already in the ViewModel so it was not needed in the Model itself. When saving and using the Model I guess using an SQL View is not allowed. You cannot save to a SQL View it is for viewing purposes only. My mistake and I am not really sure when and why I added it to the Model. Removing it did not break any code.